# Change font color by value

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, textcolor

As depending on the value on the page to change the color of the text?

```
<div [ng-Style]="color":colorFont({{item.temp.day}})> {{item.temp.day}} {{vm.symbal}}</div><br>
```

Where `{{item.temp.day}}` is data (numerical value) of which should depend on the color of text. Where "ntvg" is data (string values) which should depend on the color of the text.

If greater than 0 item.temp.day -Red  font color. Else:blue.

script:

```
$scope.colorFont=function(var templiche){
    if (parseFloat(templiche)>0) return color="red";
     else {
       return color="blue";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are mixing Angular 1 & Angular 2 whole together by using `[]`(property binding with directive).

As you are using A1 `ng-style` directive should be without placed `[]` square brackets & you shouldn't be using interpolation inside `ng-style` expression.

```
ng-style="{'color': colorFont(item.temp.day)}"
```

Additionally function would look like below

```
$scope.colorFont=function(templiche){
     if (templiche>0) return 'red';
      else {
        return 'blue';
      }
}
```

[**Forked Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1XKqbjO3lELhEUiHNz0T?p=preview)

Comment: Interestingly, ng-style directive does not work. And even,
  <Div [style.color] = " 'orange'"> style using property syntax, this text is orange </ div> does not change the color of the text

Comment: I use angular.js  How do I add this feature?

Comment: @Dmitry check updated answer, Thanks :) I added plunkr as well

Comment: @Dmitry Glad to know that, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

use return "red" <- quotation marks